# Style text-decoration differently or make a border on each line

Tags: css, border

I'm having a quite specific CSS problem. I'm trying to get a paragraph of text have a border-bottom: 1px dotted on each line while at the same time avoid writing superfluous markup.

Clearly `p {border-bottom:1px dotted #000;}` doesn't work since it will only set a border-bottom on the last line of the p tag. On the other hand, text-decoration gives the correct underlining, but can't be styled dotted.

So basically I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it than figuring out when there's a new line and add span and then style that with border-bottom and ending up with a seriously messy markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making a background that simulates a dotted line and then use that on your paragraphs. Just make sure its height has the same value as the paragraph's `line-height` attribute so it matches the rows properly.

For example, if you want your line to be a 3px dash with a 1px space, you would then make a 4px wide by X pixels high image (where X of course is the height of your text line), and just have it repeat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that option early on, but then quickly realized that the control over all browsers isn't specific enough. It's enough with like 0.2px offset in the line-height for it to get mis-aligned. Good thinking though.

Comment: @Jonas: If you use fixed pixel font sizes and declare the `line-height` attribute in pixels to match the height of your background image, it should work properly in all browsers, especially if you add a doctype to your page to make sure it won't be rendered in quirks mode. IMHO, this would be your best bet.

Comment: Seems I wasn't paying enough attention when I tried it the first time. Works perfectly across, FF, Chrome, Safari, IE7+. Good enough for me. Thanks for making me revisit it!

Comment: @Jonas: glad to be of help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since border-bottom will only work on the element identified by its selector, I can't see another way of doing this apart from wrapping the text inside every `<p>` with `<span>` tags (or another). You could avoid annoying glitches by targeting span tags *immediately* inside all p tags:

```
p > span:first-child {border-bottom:1px dotted #000;}

<p><span>this is a paragraph with a first-child span and a dotted underline<span></p>
<p>this is a paragraph with no first-child span <b>this is bold</b> <span>and this span is ignored<span></p>
```